# If first checkbox is checked , disable others based on condition

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-plugins

I have a page with a list of checkboxes with values. 
Each checkbox has data attributes with corresponding values. 
If the first checkbox is checked , I only want checkboxes whose data attributes are equal to the current checkbox's data attributes to remain selectable whilst all others are disabled.

I have got this working to a degree but if I uncheck any of the valid selected boxes, all the other checkboxes are enabled. I only want all other checkboxes to be enabled if I haven't got any valid ones selected.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <label>Number:7967</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="my-check" data-number="7867" data-code="CB45" / >
 <label>Number:3307</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="my-check" data-number="3307" data-code="HUNT1" / >
 <label>Number:3307</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="my-check" data-number="3307" data-code="HUNT1" / >
 <label>Number:5645</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="my-check" data-number="5645" data-code="KLY" / >
</body>
</html>
$(function(){


    $(".my-check").each(function (e, elem) {
            $(elem).on("change", function () {
                var num = $(this).data("number");
                var co = $(this).data("code");
                if ($(this).eq(0).is(':checked')) {

                    $('.my-check:not([data-number=' + num + '])').attr('disabled', true);
                    $('.my-check:not([data-code=' + co + '])').attr('disabled', true);
                } else {
                    $(".my-check").not($(this)).attr('disabled', false);
                }

            });

        })
```

[image]

As you can see from the image Number 3307 are selectable because they fulfill the conditions i.e data attributes are the same ... All the others are disabled. 
The issue is when I uncheck any of the valid numbers , all other boxes are enabled. I'd like all other boxes to stay disabled unless no valid numbers are checked.

[Sample code here](https://jsbin.com/vehilopora/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: "_but if I uncheck any of the valid selected boxes, all the other checkboxes are enabled. I only want all other checkboxes to be enabled if I haven't got any valid ones selected._" I am not getting this part can you give some example to explain this better. Like what you checked and un-checked then what happened, but instead what you expected!

Comment: @palaѕн I've edited the question ...hope it helps to clarify what I want to accomplish .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this issue by checking if any checkbox in current `data-*` group is checked or not. If none are checked then only enable other `.my-check` checkbox like:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".my-check").each(function(e, elem) {
    $(elem).on("change", function() {
      var num = $(this).data("number");
      var co = $(this).data("code");
      if ($(this).eq(0).is(':checked')) {
        $('.my-check:not([data-number=' + num + '])').attr('disabled', true);
        $('.my-check:not([data-code=' + co + '])').attr('disabled', true);
      } else {
        if (!$('.my-check[data-number=' + num + ']:checked').length) {
          $(".my-check").not($(this)).attr('disabled', false);
        }
      }
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Number:7967</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="my-check" data-number="7867" data-code="CB45" />
<label>Number:3307</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="my-check" data-number="3307" data-code="HUNT1" />
<label>Number:3307</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="my-check" data-number="3307" data-code="HUNT1" />
<label>Number:5645</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="my-check" data-number="5645" data-code="KLY" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $(".my-check").each(function (e, elem) {
        $(elem).on("change", function () {
            var category = this.value;
            $('.my-check').prop('checked', false);
            if ($('.my-check-' + category).val() === category)
            {
                $('.my-check-' + category).prop('checked', true);
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: This is a simplified version